# Use pathlib.Path as search pattern?

Tags: python, pathlib

I construct a path object with wildcard in it. Can I use this somehow as a search pattern for `patlib.Path.glob()`?

```
pattern = pathlib.Path('/') / 'home' / 'user' / '*' / 'folder'
result = pathlib.Path.glob(pattern)
```

Comment: Not at a machine to check, but try `**` in the middle of your path for directory globbing.

Comment: `.glob()` is an instance method, not a class method, so you can't really use it that way. Could you give an example of a directory tree and specify the expected result?

Comment: Does it have to be pathlib.Path.glob() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @InSync wrote in the comment, `pathlib.Path.glob()` is an instance method. Feeding any pattern to the class itself, will give you a TypeError:

```
>>> pathlib.Path.glob('*')
TypeError: Path.glob() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pattern'
```

You can't simply feed your instance `pattern` as a pattern for another instance either.

```
>>> list(pathlib.Path().glob(pattern))
TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not subscriptable
```

Just a quick side note: You can of course use glob.glob() and for instance feed your pattern._str into it.

```
>>> glob.glob(pattern._str)
['/home/user/this_project/folder', '/home/user/other_project/folder']
```

Or, if you want to match certain files in those 'folder' directories of the unspecified users:

```
>>> glob.glob(pattern._str + '/*.py')
['/home/user/this_project/folder/test42.py']
```

The same approach would not work in your case with another pathlib instance:

```
>>> list(pathlib.Path().glob(pattern._str))
NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported
```

And if you think about it, it does make sense. With pathlib.Path() we already have the subtree to iterate over - our_path.Path.glob(our_pattern) has no use for a pattern that is an absolute path.

If you wanted to match folders in any parent folder like in your example, you could use a differently constructed Path object to begin with (or have it created from whatever Path object you start with):

```
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/') / 'home' / 'user'
>>> list(p.glob('*/folder')
[PosixPath('/home/user/this_project/folder'), PosixPath('/home/user/other_project/folder')]
```

Or, if you want all appearances of *folder* not just on the first sublevel:

```
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/') / 'home' / 'user'
>>> list(p.glob('**/folder')
[PosixPath('/home/user/this_project/folder'), PosixPath('/home/user/other_project/folder'),PosixPath('/home/user/next_project/sup/er/de/ep/pa/th/to/folder')]

# or using pathlib.Path.rglob()
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/') / 'home' / 'user'
>>> list(p.rglob('folder')
[PosixPath('/home/user/this_project/folder'), PosixPath('/home/user/other_project/folder'),PosixPath('/home/user/next_project/sup/er/de/ep/pa/th/to/folder')]
```

**As none of that is what you apparently want**, you *could* create a `_PreciseSelector` directly and use its `_select_from()` generator to get your results as pathlib objects. Again this needs another Path instance and I think it could easily lead to confusion. After all, this is just circumventing some of the checks of pathlib.Path.glob() and *thus probably not the best idea*:

```
>>> pattern = pathlib.Path('/') / 'home' / 'user' / '*' / 'folder'
>>> sel = pathlib._make_selector(pattern.parts, pattern._flavour)
>>> list(sel.select_from(pathlib.Path()))
```

In the same way, you *could* also add to pattern.parts to match deeper results, for instance:

```
>>> pattern = pathlib.Path('/') / 'var' / 'log'
>>> sel = pathlib._make_selector(pattern.parts + ("**","*.log"), pattern._flavour)
>>> list(sel.select_from(pathlib.Path()))
# in my case PosixPath() for all *.log files found under /var/log
```